# How to avoid accents beeing displayed as question marks on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, encoding, diacritics

I'm getting a file via fs.readFile and the output shows these characters:

á (and any letter with accent), ¿, etc.

As question marks "?".

I guess it's an encoding problem, since I'm using UTF8, how can I fix this?

Comment: Output to where? Terminal window? Web browser? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

if you are showing your content in HTML

set `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`